# Error logging into admin panel.. (Fully qualified URL error)

Tags: javascript, php, magento, nginx, magento-1.7

I am facing problem in logging into admin panel.

> Error :  can’t find the server at 162.209.98.218index.php 
>   (Missing / between ip and index.php)

How can i change it in nginx server or in database?

Answer (score 1):

In database, look up the table `core_config_data` and search for `value like 'http%'`, you'll find all the url's configured. Make sure they end with a slash.

Comment: Hi, I checked in db and everything is fine... I need to config in magento... So how do i do it??? Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly this error came from your misconfiguration of NGINX or database.

So first check your database (Like search with 162.209.98.218index.php ). If you find anything fix it(Add slash). Else check your NGINX config file. So it should be like this,

```
    server {
      root     /home/magento/web/;
      index    index.php;
Listen 162.234.98.222:80; 
#server_name    ;
      location / {
        index index.html index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
        expires 30d;
      }
      location ~ ^/(app|includes|lib|media/downloadable|pkginfo|report/config.xml|var)/ { internal; }
      location /var/export/ { internal; }
      location /. { return 404; }
      location @handler { rewrite / /index.php; }
      location ~* .php/ { rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last; }
      location ~* .php$ {
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }
        expires off;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
        fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
        include fastcgi_params;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for ur answers...JNDPNT & Elavarasan. I found what the error was.. The error was with .htaccess file in magento. Its Rewritebase was missing Trialling slash(/). I fixed it.. Thx for ur time. JNDPNT & Elavarasan

Comment: Best answer for people who has moved to new server location:
1. Remove the cookies manually and 
2. Set the following cookie values :
a.Cookie Lifetime : 86400
b.Cookie Path : /
c.Cookie Domain : .domainame.com
d.Use HTTP Only : No
e.Cookie Restriction Mode : No
3. Remove the comments if any in Varien.php
// session cookie params
$cookieParams = array(
'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
'path' => $cookie->getPath(),
'domain' => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
'secure' => $cookie->isSecure(),
'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
);
4. Clear Var/cache folder
5. Reload Ctrl+Shift+R